# Assignment function "Directory.GetFiles" results to string array

Tags: c#

I want to assign function "Directory.GetFiles" results to string array using such string:

```
string[] allFoundFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@folderPath, ".jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

folderParh consists: "D:\Images\Wallpapers\1600-900".

But as a result I get an empty string array(allFoundFiles). JPG-pictures are consist in required path. Where is my error?

Comment: With `.jpg`, this method searchs exactly this named file. With `*.jpg`, you say there could be zero or more character in that file. For example, the string `*.jpg` searches for all names in path ending with the `.jpg` Read the documantation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your search pattern should be `*.jpg`, try this:

```
string[] allFoundFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@folderPath, "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Take a look at [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> **`* (asterisk):`** Zero or more characters in that position.